# add values ​from a collection to others using a column as a reference (PHP, LARAVEL)

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, collections

I am working with php in laravel, in this case I have 2 collections of objects, one of them looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product x",
        "quantity": "100",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "codProd": "product y",
        "quantity": "200",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "product a.",
        "quantity": "30",
    }
]
```

and the other looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "reference": 1,
        "quantity": "80",
    },
    {
        "reference": 2,
        "quantity": "50",
    },
]
```

What I need is to keep the first collection but adding the value of the quantity key from the second collection, using the reference key as a relationship with the id of the first collection, the final result should look like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "product x",
        "quantity": "180",
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "codProd": "product y",
        "quantity": "250",
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "product a.",
        "quantity": "30",
    }
]
```

so how can I do this?, any guide or help I am grateful

Answer (score 0):

You can use a collection method for this, the **map** method:

```
$collection_one = collect([
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'product x',
        'quantity' => 100,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 2,
        'name' => 'product y',
        'quantity' => 100,
    ],
    [
        'id' => 1,
        'name' => 'product a.',
        'quantity' => 30,
    ],
]);

$collection_two = collect([
    [
        'reference' => 1,
        'quantity' => 80,
    ],
    [
        'reference' => 2,
        'quantity' => 50,
    ],
]);
```

For you to get the collection what you want:

```
$collect = [];

$collect = $collection_one->map(function ($value_one) use ($collection_two) {
    if ($search = $collection_two->firstWhere('reference', '=', $value_one['id'])) {
        $value_one['quantity'] += $search['quantity'];
    }

    return $value_one;
});
```

Ready, that worked for me. :)